Form validation fails
I try to create form for POST the new user but have a problem.
I use the bootstrap form validation (Browser defaults).
Have a button:
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-addUser" type="submit">Add User</button>

This button also has the function of creating a new post based on the data from the input:
const addUsersBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-addUser");

// post add button in html
addUsersBtn.addEventListener("click", postNewUser);

// Post a user
function postNewUser(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // write value from form inputs
  const name = form.elements.namedItem("name").value;
  const username = form.elements.namedItem("username").value;
  const email = form.elements.namedItem("email").value;
  const phone = form.elements.namedItem("phone").value;
  const website = form.elements.namedItem("website").value;

  // create our user object from data recorded in variables from form inputs
  const newPost = {
    name: name,
    username: username,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    website: website,
    user_id: `id_${Math.random() * Math.random()}`,
  };

  // create a post
  createPost(newPost, (response) => {
    const card = newPostTemplate(response);
    container.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", card);
    form.reset();
    initPopovers();
  });
}

But if i use the function postNewUser validation has not work.
If i delete the "btn-addUser" class from button validation works.
My code from addUser.js file:
// получаем нашу форму
const form = document.forms["addUser"];
// create a “create post” function
function createPost(body, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    request.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      //   console.log(response);
      if (request.status >= 400) {
        reject(request.response);
      } else {
        resolve(request.response);
      }
      callback(response);
    });
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
  });
}
// template for the post in which it will be built
function newPostTemplate(post) {
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  card.classList.add("card");

  const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
  cardBody.classList.add("card-body");

  const userBtn = document.createElement("button");
  userBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  userBtn.classList.add("btn", "btn-info", "btn-lg");
  userBtn.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "popover");
  userBtn.setAttribute("data-bs-html", "true");
  userBtn.setAttribute(
    "data-bs-title",
    "Additional information about the user: "
  );
  userBtn.setAttribute(
    "data-bs-content",
    `Username: ${post.username}<br/>Email: ${post.email}<br/>Phone: ${post.phone}<br/> Website: ${post.website}`
  );
  const title = document.createElement("h5");
  title.classList.add("card-title");
  title.textContent = post.name;

  userBtn.appendChild(title);
  cardBody.appendChild(userBtn);
  card.appendChild(cardBody);
  return card;
}
// button to add post in html
addUsersBtn.addEventListener("click", postNewUser);
// function Post user
function postNewUser(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // write value from form inputs
  const name = form.elements.namedItem("name").value;
  const username = form.elements.namedItem("username").value;
  const email = form.elements.namedItem("email").value;
  const phone = form.elements.namedItem("phone").value;
  const website = form.elements.namedItem("website").value;
  // create our user object from data recorded in variables from form inputs
  const newPost = {
    name: name,
    username: username,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    website: website,
    user_id: `id_${Math.random() * Math.random()}`,
  };
  // create a post
  createPost(newPost, (response) => {
    const card = newPostTemplate(response);
    container.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", card);
    form.reset();
    initPopovers();
  });
}


I wanna ask some questions:

Can I create two buttons: first button without 'btn-addUser' class and second button with 'btn-addUser' class? I want to add a button disabled state (bootstrap) and remove them when submit without 'btn-addUser' class receives a positive response from validation. After click button with 'btn-addUser' this button will be disabled.
It's really? I don't know how to get a positive response from validation.
Or maybe I'm doing garbage and it can be done much simpler?


You are reacting to a click event on your submit button, and prevent that event's default action (submitting the form) - so the form validation will never trigger. If your form doesn't have any other submit buttons (that need to do something different), then just bind this to the submit event of the form instead. If you need to handle different buttons differently - then you need to trigger the validation yourself (via the form's checkValidity method.)

Can you translate your comments to english?

I translated the comments into English

e.preventDefault() in your submit event handler likely prevents browser to automatically perform its built-in validation checks when the form attempts to submit. You should manuallly check if form is valid using form.checkValidity() like this:
function postNewUser(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    // Form is valid, proceed with creating the new user
    // Add your custom logic here
  } else {
    // Form is invalid, trigger validation UI
    // form.classList.add("was-validated");
  }
}

Make sure your form has the necessary Bootstrap validation attributes and classes, such as novalidate on the form element and the appropriate validation classes on the form inputs.

Thank you so much. It works. You are all cool guys, I learn from you every day, thank you.

I am not sure why you are doing things like that, simple validations can also be set if you put the required into it.
Yes, you can do a lot simpler than this.
And yes you can use classes or id for it.
ids are much simpler and unique entities. You can set attribute to disabled or you can hide that button from doing simple styling by display:none;

The idea is exactly this:

I'm making a POST request;
The post request passes if the form is valid (all fields are filled in)
The post request does not go through if the form is not valid (some of the fields are empty)
Required using browser defaults bootstrap validation.

